# SQLite with full-text index and B-tree index on another column

Tags: sqlite, indexing, full-text-search

I have a table like this:

```
id | status | message
1  | 200    | Some long text
2  | 400    | Other text
```

Sometimes I need to find a row based on the id, sometimes based on the status (including *range queries*), sometimes I need to filter based on some words contained in the message. And sometimes I need to filter based on a mix of conditions on all columns.

The problem is that I have two alternatives:

- Use a virtual table FTS5 for full-text search
- Use a normal table with the index on id and status

It seems that I can't have both... Am I missing something? What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can have both, though.

Add the needed indexes to your table. And then create an [external content FTS5 table](https://sqlite.org/fts5.html#external_content_tables) that uses it as the backing store.

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, status INTEGER, message TEXT);
CREATE INDEX my_table_status_idx ON my_table(status);
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE my_table_fts USING fts5(message, content=my_table, content_rowid=id);
```

and then update the FTS table appropriately when inserting or deleting rows from `my_table`. The documentation gives example triggers to automate this part.